# Assembly socket creation crash

Tags: sockets, assembly, fasm

this is my Assembly source code for windows socket (ws2)

this program compiled without any problem but on execution time, program crash (for seconds, program do nothing)

what is the problem ? i think the problem is about stack or ...

```
format PE CONSOLE
entry start

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
section '.bss' writeable readable
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

        ____STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE     RD 1
        ____SOCKET                RD 1
        ____LPWSADATA             RB 400

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
section '.text' code readable executable
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

start:
        sub     esp, 16 ; struct sockaddr_in

        ; GetStdHandle
        push    -11
        call    [GetStdHandle]
        test    eax, eax
        jz      .exit
        mov     [____STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE], eax

        ; WSAStartup
        push    ____LPWSADATA
        push    2
        call    [WSAStartup]
        test    eax, eax
        jnz     .init_failed

        ; SOCKET
        push    6
        push    1
        push    2
        call    [socket]
        test    eax, eax
        jz      .socket_failed

        ; HTONS (PORT)
        push    80
        call    [htons]
        mov     [esp+2], WORD ax                ; sin_port = htons(port)

        ; SOCKADDR
        mov     [esp], WORD 2                   ; sin_family = AF_INET
        mov     [esp+4], DWORD 2130706433       ; sin_addr   = 127.0.0.1 (addr in long = (2130706433))

        ; BIND
        push    16
        lea     eax, [esp]
        push    eax
        push    [____SOCKET]
        call    [bind]
        test    eax, eax
        jnz     .bind_failed

        ; LISTEN
        push    5               ; SOMAXCONN
        push    [____SOCKET]
        call    [listen]
        test    eax, eax
        jnz     .listen_failed

        ; CLOSE
        ; ...
        ; ...


        jmp     .exit


        .init_failed:
                push    0
                push    0
                push    DWORD [.err0_len]
                push    DWORD .err0
                push    [____STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE]
                call    [WriteFile]
                jmp     .exit

        .socket_failed:
                push    0
                push    0
                push    DWORD [.err1_len]
                push    DWORD .err1
                push    [____STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE]
                call    [WriteFile]
                jmp     .exit

        .bind_failed:
                push    0
                push    0
                push    DWORD [.err2_len]
                push    DWORD .err2
                push    [____STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE]
                call    [WriteFile]
                jmp     .exit

        .listen_failed:
                push    0
                push    0
                push    DWORD [.err3_len]
                push    DWORD .err3
                push    [____STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE]
                call    [WriteFile]
                jmp     .exit

        .exit:
                push    0
                call    [ExitProcess]
                hlt

        .err0:
                DB      'Socket initialization failed', 0x0A, 0x00

        .err0_len:
                DD      $ - .err0

        .err1:
                DB      'Socket creation failed', 0x0A, 0x00

        .err1_len:
                DD      $ - .err1

        .err2:
                DB      'Socket bind failed', 0x0A, 0x00

        .err2_len:
                DD      $ - .err2

        .err3:
                DB      'Socket listen failed', 0x0A, 0x00

        .err3_len:
                DD      $ - .err3


;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
section '.idata' import data readable writeable
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

        DD      0,0,0,RVA kernel_name, RVA kernel_list
        DD      0,0,0,0,0

        DD      0,0,0,RVA ws2_name, RVA ws2_list
        DD      0,0,0,0,0

        kernel_list:
                ExitProcess     DD RVA _ExitProcess
                GetStdHandle    DD RVA _GetStdHandle
                WriteFile       DD RVA _WriteFile
                CloseHandle     DD RVA _CloseHandle
                                DD 0

        kernel_name:        DB 'KERNEL32.DLL', 0

        _ExitProcess:           DB 0,0,'ExitProcess',0
        _GetStdHandle:          DB 0,0,'GetStdHandle',0
        _WriteFile:             DB 0,0,'WriteFile',0
        _CloseHandle:           DB 0,0,'CloseHandle',0

        ws2_list:
                socket                  DD RVA _socket
                htons                   DD RVA _htons
                WSAStartup              DD RVA _WSAStartup
                WSACleanup              DD RVA _WSACleanup
                WSAGetLastError         DD RVA _WSAGetLastError
                getpeername             DD RVA _getpeername
                bind                    DD RVA _bind
                listen                  DD RVA _listen
                accept                  DD RVA _accept
                recv                    DD RVA _recv
                send                    DD RVA _send
                setsockopt              DD RVA _setsockopt
                shutdown                DD RVA _shutdown
                closesocket             DD RVA _closesocket
                                        DD 0

        ws2_name:           DB 'WS2_32.DLL', 0

        _socket:                DB 0,0,'socket',0
        _htons:                 DB 0,0,'htons', 0
        _WSAStartup:            DB 0,0,'WSAStartup',0
        _WSACleanup:            DB 0,0,'WSACleanup',0
        _WSAGetLastError:       DB 0,0,'WSAGetLastError',0
        _getpeername:           DB 0,0,'getpeername',0
        _bind:                  DB 0,0,'bind',0
        _listen:                DB 0,0,'listen',0
        _accept:                DB 0,0,'accept',0
        _recv:                  DB 0,0,'recv',0
        _send:                  DB 0,0,'send',0
        _setsockopt:            DB 0,0,'setsockopt',0
        _shutdown:              DB 0,0,'shutdown',0
        _closesocket:           DB 0,0,'closesocket',0
```

Should i use (add esp, x) for each function ... ?? is this the problem?
or the problem is about function linking ?

Comment: Use your debugger to at least pinpoint the location of the crash.

Comment: in fact, it's not crash ... it's freeze for seconds and then exist ...

Comment: You forgot to write the socket handle into the `____SOCKET` variable.

Comment: yes but this is not the problem .... at least, if ____SOCKET is invalid, it's must return error !!! but this program freeze !!!

Comment: Use your debugger to break into the process when it's stuck so you can see which function is blocking.

Answer (score 0):

i found the problem ... the problem is linking ... my linking is wrong because i used the default macro of fASM (for linking) and it's worked without any problem ... now what is the problem of my linking ?!!!!!